# Baseboards with huge nails

Tags: baseboard

Theres huge nails in my baseboards. Ive tried a few tricks but still results in a torn up wall. Any suggestions

Comment: A photo would be helpful and a clear question. Are you installing / removing nails? I am not sure. Trim should be installed with finish nails and set or wire brads with a gun. For removal a photo or a description of the nail not just huge because to me anything other than a finishing nail would be huge in trim.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to conceal the nails? Remove them? Please revise your question to make that more clear.

Comment: *Yes i ave a suggestion*. Give us some information so we know what your goal is and why that is the goal. Tell us what you have tried, how and why.  **Please tell us what you are talking about**.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As others have said, we'll need more info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: also can you explain what you have tried. If you are removing the baseboards are you using a specific tool?